# Is the usage of "labeled" preferred to the usage of "named"?

Tags: word-choice

Considering the description of a method in a research paper, which is the most natural way to express how we refer to the method? Is there a rule about when to use named vs labeled?

1. In this paper, we will describe our new method **named** "KICK".
2. In this paper, we will describe our new method **labeled** "KICK".
3. In this paper, we will describe our new method **called** "KICK".
4. In this paper, we will describe our new method, "KICK".

Comment: I don't know of any rule myself, but "named" sounds more natural here.

Comment: "christened" *could* work... :D

Comment: @JM - I'd use 'christened' informally, but not in a formal research paper. God only knows who would be up in arms about the use of such words. [See what I did there? **;)** ]

Comment: "dubbed" would also probably be appropriate.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers. But as RegDwight and Eric pointed out, "called" is also an alternative. I edited my question accordingly.

Comment: “Christened” can’t work because a) methods are not baptized, and b) it makes no sense to readers who are not Christians.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A name is different than a label.

> Name: a word by which a person or thing is known
>
> Label: an identifying or descriptive marker that is attached to an object

So a label might have your name on it, but often it has something else on it, such as a warning, or description, or classification.

A rule of thumb is that names are unique(ish) and labels are not.

In the example question, it looks like the word you want is "name".

Consider this website: the question's name is the question headline itself: "Is the usage of 'labeled' preferred to the usage of 'named'?".  The question's labels are its tags: "usage".

**Edit:**
I just noticed your edit to this question. The third and fourth sentences carry the same meaning as "named". You are "called" by your name, usually. I'd use "named" or go with the fourth option, which just names the method. There are lots of synonyms for "name" but, importantly, "label" isn't really one of them.

**Edit 2:**
[Google's built-in dictionary defines label as](https://www.google.ca/search?q=define%20label&rct=j)

> a classifying phrase or name applied to a person or thing, especially one that is inaccurate or restrictive.

This strengthens the notion that while labels are related to names, names are not a subset of labels (though labels might be said to be a subset of names).

Comment: "names are unique(ish)" - I'd emphasize the "ish" myself... :)

Comment: @J. M.: Yeah, it's pretty ish, but it depends on the domain. Drug names, for example, tend to be unique in a country, but the warning labels on the bottles are certainly generic. Class names in computer programing must be unique within their namespace but there's no guarantee that someone somewhere else didn't use the same classname as you; however you probably will never see their code. etc.

Comment: "Drug names, for example, tend to be unique in a country" - nowadays, yes, but at least about two decades ago, no. Witness "acetaminophen" versus "paracetamol" and "albuterol" versus "salbutamol"...

Comment: a name is a label

Comment: @Unreason: In some cases I'd agree that a name is a label. But in many cases I'd disagree. 'Label' and 'name' don't have the same connotations at all, so much so that I'd say it'd be wrong to say that when my parents named me, they labelled me.

Comment: But they sure gave you a descriptive marker attached to an object, or as the bard would say: what's in the name? ;)

Comment: My name is not descriptive. And the difference is in the connotations.

Comment: A name is not a label. If it was, we wouldn’t have the two different words. Something can have only one name but it can have unlimited labels.

Answer (score 4):

Named is preferred in your example, since you are formally giving a name to *your* method.

Labelling (beyond the literal) generally infers that *someone else* has suggested an alternative name for something.

> Microsoft named their browser 'Internet Explorer', but it's often labelled as 'Internet Exploder'!

**Edit**:
Labelling is something you do when you categorise something informally; that is, you are attaching a virtual label to it, some meta-data, if you will. For example,

> Critics have labelled Project X a disaster from start to finish

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Labelling

Comment: Does that mean that "labelled" should be used when you call something by a name that is not "official" or known in the domain?

Comment: "when you call something by a name that is not "official" or known in the domain?" - I'd use "nicknamed", but that's just me...

Comment: @xmoleslo: I'd agree with JM that 'nickame' is probably more descriptive in that example. I've updated my post to provide a different (better?) example.

Comment: Definitely 'called'.

Comment: @Eric: 'Called' was not one of the two alternatives offered by the OP.

Comment: @CJM: While true, neither of the alternatives offered by the OP are suitable.

Comment: Name is perfectly suitable - it's purely dependent on the individuals style and preferences.

Answer (score 2):

*Name* is a better choice than *label* if you are giving a name to something new. The latter is used when you want to describe or give information about something instead.

For example, we say *name the baby* but not *label the baby*, *don't label me as stupid* but not *don't name me as stupid*, and *label the medication with this sticker* but not *name the medication with this sticker*.

Comment: What if _KICK_ is an acronym that would be descriptive enough, so that one would know more or less what kind of method it is?

Answer (score 2):

Pardon the brevity of this answer, but I would say "named" is preferred within the context of your example. Thus:

```
In this paper, we will describe our new method named "KICK".
```

Better still, you can omit "named" or "labeled" altogether for succinctness:

```
In this paper, we will describe our new method, "KICK".
```

The comma before "KICK" is sometimes treated as a matter of preference.

Answer (score 1):

You should actually use neither.  The implication is obvious:

> Here we discuss our new method "Fantastic Method".

To draw a parallel:

> Here we discuss our child named Thomas.

Or:

> Here we discuss our child labeled Thomas.